# Why is my @Effect overwriting existing state with ngrx in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am using ngrx in an Angular 6 app and I can successfully load data from a database and display it on the screen.  However, when I navigate to a new page in the app and then navigate back, the state is not preserved and it appears the `@Effect` is called again and loads the data from the database again.  Here is my code:

**Effect**

```
export class ProductEffects {
    constructor(private productService: ProductService, private actions$: Actions) { }

    @Effect()
    loadProducts$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(productActions.LOAD_ACTION),
        switchMap(action =>
            this.productsService.getProductDetails().pipe(
                map(product => new productActions.LoadSuccess(product)),
                catchError(err => of(new productActions.LoadError(err)))
            )
        )
    );
```

**Reducer**

```
export interface ProductState {
    product: Product;
}

const initialState: ProductState = {
    product: {}
};

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: Action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_PRODUCT:
            return { ...state, product: (action as SetProductAction).payload };

        case LOAD_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, product: (action as LoadSuccess).payload, error: '' };

        default: return state;
    }
}
```

**Actions**

```
export const SET_PRODUCT = '[Product] Set Product';
export const LOAD = '[Product] Load';
export const LOAD_SUCCESS = '[Product] Load Success';
export const LOAD_ERROR = '[Product] Load Error';

export class SetProductAction implements Action {
    readonly type = SET_PRODUCT;
    constructor(public payload: Product) { }
}

export class Load implements Action {
    readonly type = LOAD;
}

export class LoadSuccess implements Action {
    readonly type = LOAD_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public payload: Product) { }
}

export type ProductActions = SetProduct | Load | LoadSuccess;
```

**Store**

```
export interface State extends fromRoot.AppState {
    product: fromProduct.ProductState;
}

// selectors
const getProductState = createFeatureSelector<fromProduct.ProductState>('product');

export const getProduct = createSelector(
    getProductState,
    state => state.product
}
```

**Component**

```
products$: Observable<Product>;

constructor(private store: Store<fromProduct.State>) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new Load());
    this.products$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromProduct.getProduct));
}
```

Comment: You don't have a `resolver` or a `guard` to handle if it's `loaded`, so from what I can see that's the expected behavior based on your code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ngrx implementation seems all ok to me. What you describe is an absolutely normal behavior. As soon as you navigate away from a page, the component destroyed and the new one is created, i.e. the ngOnInit is called. If you put the Loading logic in the ngOnInit, the state is loaded everytime you navigate to this page.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  In my `@Effect`, it added the `take(1)` RxJS operator before my `switchMap`.  It seems to have solved the problem, the state is preserved from feature to feature and page to page.

Comment: Yes this is possible in this case. I think the disadvantage is, that dispatching a second load-action (maybe later) will have no effect I think.

Comment: I am seeing in my dev tools that the Load action is being called each time I go back to the page, with the state preserved.  Currently I am only doing one load but will see if a second load will do nothing.

Comment: I have an app where I dispatch the loading actions as soon the app/module is loaded. This will happen asynchronously in the background. As soon as the user navigates to the component, the data is already there and so he/she has not to wait till the data is loaded.

Comment: I thought about that too.  My app is using lazy loading so I would most likely put this load effect in the feature component, and then whenever the feature is hit, the data is already there.  Same concept as doing it in the App Load.  Thanks :-)